# Protractor - MouseMove not supported for Firefox

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, protractor

I am new to protractor and selenium. I am trying to simulate the mouse hover action on a button and read the values like mouse pointer value and background colors. I am using mousemove and it works fine in Chrome but not when I set the browser to Firefox. I believe the webdriver is not supporting this for some reason.

```
it('Mouse cursor should change to hand pointer', function() {   
  browser.get('URL');
  var search = element(by.buttonText('SEARCH'));
  browser.actions().mouseMove(search).perform();
  expect(search.getCssValue("cursor")).toEqual('pointer');
});
```

I am getting the following error for Firefox:

```
Message:
 Failed: mouseMoveTo
 Build info: version: '3.1.0',                 
 java.version: '1.8.0_121'
 Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver  
Stack:  
 UnsupportedOperationError: mouseMoveTo
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the firefox version details

Comment: Firefox Version: 51.0.1 (32-bit)

Answer (score 1):

`mouseMove` works fine for me. Looks like an issue for you with `Firefox Version - gecko driver version - Protractor Version` combination
Suggest you to upgrade all 3 to the latest versions available

I tried with the below combo and its all good

- geckodriver-v0.9.0
- Firefox - 45.0
- Protractor - Version 4.0.10

Comment: Hi, I am using the latest versions available but it still doesn't work. These are my versions:         
Protractor Version 5.1.1
geckodriver 0.14.0
Firefox 51.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into a similar issue. Seems like it might be related to the changes in selenium 3.1.0 (I just upgraded from 2.53.1).

```
(node:8988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): UnsupportedOperationError: mouseMoveTo
Build info: version: '3.1.0', revision: '86a5d70', time: '2017-02-16 07:57:44 -0800'
System info: host: 'EC2AMAZ-GHIOFIE', ip: '10.199.2.240', os.name: 'Windows NT (unknown)', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
(node:8988) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
```

Selenium: 3.1.0

Firefox: 51

Protractor: 5.1.1

Comment: There is an open issue for this on the [Selenium github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3693)